# Configuring sendmail for several domain names

Tags: apache2, email, postfix, mail, sendmail

So here's the problem: I have a webserver that's currently serving quite a number of different domain names as virtual hosts for apache. Lets say the default domain is `defaultdomain.com`

When I use sendmail (via PHPMailer) from `otherdomain.com`, the mail that is sent has the header `Received: from defaultdomain.com`, even though I set the `From` header to `noreply@otherdomain.com`

I suspect the mismatch is why these emails are being filtered as spam (from what I've read on the [gmail spam filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858#unconfirmed))

What configuration in the email headers, sendmail, or postfix do I need to change to ensure emails from other virtual hosts are actually sent from their respective domain names, and thus no longer filtered as spam?